# Python multipart upload not taking content-type

Tags: python, python-requests, multipartform-data

I am tying to use python requests framework for multipart upload,follwoing is my code:

```
import requests


def myfc()
{
url = "https://myurl"

payload={}
files=[
  ('request',('test.yaml',open('/Users/test/test.yaml'))
]
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  'Authorization': 'test'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files,verify=False)

print(response.text)
}
print(' 1')
t1 = threading.Thread(target=myfc, args=())
print(' 2')
t2 = threading.Thread(target=myfc, args=())
print(' 3')
t3 = threading.Thread(target=myfc, args=())
t1.start()
```

If i remove 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',from headers and keep only Authorization then it works fine, but If i keep 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',then it give 404 response.Why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import requests

def myfc():
    url = "https://myurl"

    payload={}

    files= {
        'test.yaml' : open('/Users/test/test.yaml', 'r')
    }
    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      'Authorization': 'test'
    }

    with requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files,verify=False) as response:
        response.raise_for_status()
        print(response.text)

print(' 1')
t1 = threading.Thread(target=myfc, args=())
print(' 2')
t2 = threading.Thread(target=myfc, args=())
print(' 3')
t3 = threading.Thread(target=myfc, args=())
t1.start()
```