# Adding "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" on headers on a POST request showing KeyError but showing success message while removing it

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to play around with REST Api. I was practicing to write a `server-side` and `client-side` python script, where client will upload a file in the server. The following is `server` and `client` side code in python.

```py
# server.py
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/api/upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload_image():
    # Get the image file from the request body
    image_file = request.files["image"]

    # Save the image file to a specific location
    image_file.save("images/image11.jpg")
    
    return "Image uploaded successfully", 200

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```py
# client.py
import requests

# Set the API endpoint URL
url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/upload"

# Set the image file to be uploaded
image_file = "C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Image\\an.jpg"

# Set the request headers
headers = {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
}

image_file_descriptor = open(image_file, 'rb')
# Requests makes it simple to upload Multipart-encoded files 
files = {'image': image_file_descriptor}

# Send the POST request with the image file as a key-value pair
response = requests.post(url, files=files)

# Print the response status code
print(response.status_code)
```

This code works fine. The image saved into the mentioned directory in the name of `image11.jpg` and also returned 200. However, if I initiate the POST request in `client.py` with `header` like this - `requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers)` then it shows following error -

```
400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'image'
```

I tried to remove the `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"` from `headers`, tried to pass the `headers` with nothing written inside and writing `"Authorization": "Bearer 1514"` inside. It was working in both situation.

I also tried to send the request from tools like Postman/[Advanced REST client (ARC)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo). It also worked and the file transferred successfully and returned 200.

[image]

I have tried find out some solutions out there. Tried to check similar questions on StackOverflow. The following one seems to be a similar one-
Link: [Python multipart upload not taking content-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68346505/python-multipart-upload-not-taking-content-type)

But failed to find the exact reason. Can anyone help me to figure out the reason.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to get to the bottom of that by reading Flask's code, will just point why Flask complains/errors.

If you add `print request.headers` in your method, you will see what headers Flask receives.

If you don't set the header `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"`, requests will automatically add this one to the request:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=072c2c6e071d5dbc3423739ceb4e048b
```

If you set the header, then the `boundary` portion is lost, and Flask complains.

If you use web form to upload a file like:

```
@app.route("/api/upload", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload_image():
    if request.method == "POST":
      .....
    else:
        return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Upload new File</title>
    <h1>Upload new File</h1>
    <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
      <input type=file name=image>
      <input type=submit value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''
```

and upload from your browser, you will see the boundary part also present:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:108.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/108.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------57875131084340261312514205
Content-Length: 85295
```

In summary: I'm not sure of the details, but Flask/werkzeug requires the `boundary` in that header, which is populated by the clients (even Python's `requests`).